How do I find all positive integers $n, k$, such that $(n+k)^k - 1=n!$?
I need to solve the equation $$(n+k)^k - 1 = n!$$ over positive integers.I managed to do it only for odd $k$. Here is how I did it:

I started with proving that $n\geq k$, because otherwise $(n+k)^k-1>(n+n)^n-1>n^n-1$, which is greater than $n!$ for all $n>1$ (I'm going to consider the case $n=1$ in the end).
The main idea is to transform $(n+k)^k-1$ to other polyminal:
$$(n+k)^k-1=n! \leftrightarrow (n+k)^k+1=n!+2 \rightarrow n+k+1|n!+2\rightarrow \boxed{\gcd(n!, n+k+1)=2}.$$
But as $k\leq n$, $\frac{n+k+1}{2}\leq \lfloor\frac{n+n+1}{2}\rfloor=\lfloor n+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor =n$. And as $n!$ is divisible by all positive integers, that are less or equal to $n$, $\boxed{\frac{n+k+1}{2}|n!}$.
Both of these statements can be true only if $n+k+1\in \{2, 4\}\rightarrow n+k\in\{1, 3\}$. Considering this, I found that the only solution is $\bf (n, k)=(2, 1)$.
And as I missed the cases when $n!$ is odd (this is true only if $n\leq 1$) and when $n=1$, I consired $n=0$ and $n=1$ and found an other solution $\bf (n_2, k_2)=(1,1)$.

It would be interesting how you did it

@ajotatxe You did it! See here.

The base is $n+k$. In my post is $n+1$.

Maybe note:  $(n+k)^k - 1=(n+k-1)[(n+k)^{k-1}+..... + 1]$ so $n+k-1|n!$  so $\gcd(n+k,n!)=1$ so either $k > n$ or $k=1$.

But I don't understand, why if $n+k-1|n!$, $gcd(n+k, n!)=1$?

Take n=6, k=3..

$n+k$ must be a prime (otherwise take $p\mid n+k$ with $p\leq n$ and check the equation mod $p$, for this also notice that $n+k\leq 2n$)

Since you've handled odd $k$, consider just even $k$. Since $n \gt 1$, then $n + k$ is odd, so $2 \mid (n + k) - 1$. Thus, using the Lifting-the-exponent lemma for $p = 2$ and an even exponent, we get
$$\nu_2((n + k)^k - 1) = \nu_2(n + k - 1) + \nu_2(n + k + 1) + \nu_2(k) - 1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$
Among $n + k \pm 1$, one is congruent to $0$ modulo $4$ while the other is congruent to $2$. Let $c$ be the value divisible by $4$. Then \eqref{eq1A} becomes
$$\nu_2((n + k)^k - 1) = \nu_2(c) + \nu_2(k) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$
Since $n \neq k$, your $k \le n$ is $k \lt n$, so $c \le n + k + 1 \le 2n$. Also, $\log_2(j) \ge \nu_2(j)$ for all positive integers $j$. Thus,
$$\log_2(2n^2) = \log_2(2n) + \log_2(n) \gt \nu_2((n + k)^k - 1) \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$
Next, the even integers $2, 4, \ldots, n - 1$ each have at least a single factor of $2$, so we get
$$\nu_2(n!) \ge \frac{n-1}{2} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$
Using that $(n + k)^k - 1 = n! \;\to\; \nu_2((n + k)^k - 1) = \nu_2(n!)$, then \eqref{eq3A} and \eqref{eq4A} together gives
$$\log_2(2n^2) \gt \frac{n-1}{2} \;\;\to\;\; 2n^2 \gt 2^{\frac{n - 1}{2}} \;\;\to\;\; n^2 \gt 2^{\frac{n - 3}{2}} \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$
Although exponentials to a base $\gt 1$ will always eventually grow larger than any polynomial, I'll prove this specific case using induction.  For $n = 21$, we have $n^2 = 21^2 = 441$ and $2^{\frac{n - 3}{2}} = 2^{9} = 512$, so \eqref{eq5A} doesn't hold then. Assume that
$$2^{\frac{n - 3}{2}} \gt n^2 \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$
is true for some odd $n = m$ where $m \ge 21$. We have
$$m(m - 4) \gt 4 \;\;\to\;\; m^2 \gt 4m + 4 \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$
Thus, we also get
$$2^{\frac{(m + 2) - 3}{2}} = 2^{\frac{m - 3}{2}} + 2^{\frac{m - 3}{2}} \gt m^2 + (4m + 4) = (m + 2)^2 \tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$
This shows \eqref{eq6A} is also true for $n = m + 2$. Thus, by induction, it's true for all odd $n \ge 21$. As such, we only need to consider odd $n \lt 21$. Note the problem equation for even $k$ is a special case of Brocard's problem. As shown there, for $n$ up to one quadrillion, the only odd $n$ solutions are $5! + 1 = 11^2$ and $7! + 1 = 71^2$, with neither one being applicable in our case.
Thus, there are no solutions for even $k$. Note a similar procedure to the above could also be used for odd $k$.
